# Dar formato a JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, mysqli

Quiero dar un formato especifico a un JSON que hago desde PHP para despues recibirlo en una variable en JS y llenar una tabla con el, pero no se como hacerlo.

Aqui se crea el JSON:

```
<?php 
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas_maps") or die ("Problemas con la conexion");
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM registros2";
    $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas con la consulta");
    $c = array();
    while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
    {
        array_push($c,
                   array($reg['id'],$reg['cliente'],$reg['metodo_pago'],$reg['hora'],$reg['fecha_entrega'], $reg['sem_entrega']));
    }
    echo json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
?>
```

Y lo imprime con esta estructura:

```
{
 0: {
  0: "100",
  1: "Carlos Luna",
  2: "Credito 30D",
  3: "14:15:00",
  4: "2018-05-09",
  5: "19"
 },
 1: {
  0: "104",
  1: "sadfsadf",
  2: "Contado",
  3: "12:32:00",
  4: "2018-06-18",
  5: "25"
 }
}
```

Y necesito que se imprima asi:

```
[
 0: "{"id":"100","cliente":"Carlos Luna","metodo_pago":"Credito 30D","hora_entrega":"14:15:00","fecha_entrega":"2018-05-09","sem_entrega":"19"}",
 1: "{"id":"104","cliente":"sadfsadf","metodo_pago":"Contado","hora_entrega":"12:32:00","fecha_entrega":"2018-06-18","sem_entrega":"25"}"
]
```

La funcion donde la voy a recibir es esta:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ejemplo1').DataTable();
        var res = <?php echo json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>;
        MostrarRegistros();
    });

    function MostrarRegistros(){
        $('#tblRegistros tr:not(:first)').remove();
        for(var i in res)
        {
            var con = JSON.parse(res[i]);
            $('#tblRegistros tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+con.id+'</td><td>'+con.cliente+'</td><td>'+con.metodo_pago+'</td><td>'+con.fecha_entrega+'</td><td>'+con.sem_entrega+'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Debería hacerlo con el primer código, si le quitas esto `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT `

Comment: Casi esta pero no es el formato. Lo imprime asi:

`[
  ["100","Carlos Luna","Credito 30D","14:15:00","2018-05-09","19"], 
  ["104","sadfsadf","Contado","12:32:00","2018-06-18","25"]
]`

Comment: pues tu no estas asignando ninguna clave al array

Comment: array_push($c,
                   array('id'=>$reg['id'],..........)

Answer (score 2):

si le quieres dar el formato especifico te recomiedo que cambies tu array

```
    array($reg['id'],$reg['cliente'],$reg['metodo_pago'],$reg['hora'],$reg['fecha_entrega'], $reg['sem_entrega']));
```

por el siguiente:

```
    array('id'=>$reg['id'],
       'cliente'=>$reg['cliente'],
       'metodo_pago'=>$reg['metodo_pago'],
       'hora'=>$reg['hora'],
       'fecha_entrega'=>$reg['fecha_entrega'], 
       'sem_entrega'=>$reg['sem_entrega'])
    );
```

Y asi le asignas los identificadores que desees amigo, saludos. y te dejo el enlace de manejo de arrays de php:[PHP ARRAYS MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

Comment: en efecto te falta asignar las claves, caso contrario se designa los numeros como ya viste en tu resultado...!!! @CarlosRobertoLunaOchoa

Comment: Casi esta amigo, eso me funciono, pero aun no tiene el formato. Lo imprime asi: `[{id:"100",cliente:"Carlos Luna",metodo_pago:"Credito 30D",hora:"14:15:00",fecha_entrega:"2018-05-09",sem_entrega:"19"}]` y necesito que los elementos me los imprima como string, asi: `["{"id":"100","cliente":"Carlos Luna","metodo_pago":"Credito 30D","hora":"14:15:00","fecha_entrega":"2018-05-09","sem_entrega":"19"}"]` del lado de JS para poder insertarlos en la tabla, o estoy haciendo algo mal en el script?

Comment: perdon amigo seria que reemplaces de la siguiente manera: `array_push($c,         array(    array('id'=>$reg['id'],
       'cliente'=>$reg['cliente'],
       'metodo_pago'=>$reg['metodo_pago'],
       'hora'=>$reg['hora'],
       'fecha_entrega'=>$reg['fecha_entrega'], 
       'sem_entrega'=>$reg['sem_entrega'])
    ));`
ahora pues bien si lo que deseas es hacerlo string podrias utilizar la funcion implode(",", $array); de php, pero en realidad no lo veo necesrio ya que si lo dejas hecho array, se puede manipular mejor

Comment: Y no habra una forma de darle el formato que quiero del lado de JS? O llenar la tabla de manera que pueda usar el JSON que obtengo desde PHP?

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es mostrar estos datos del lado del cliente mediante JS ?? o usando json

Comment: El formato que necesito debe de estar del lado de JS para poder hacer las filas de la tabla con la informacion que trae el JSON desde PHP

Comment: reemplaza esta linea `echo json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` por lo siguiente `$textualizado=json_encode($c);
$textualizado=json_encode(array(
        $textualizado));
echo str_replace('\\', '', $textualizado);`

Answer (score 0):

Estás teniendo tantos problemas para obtener los datos como los quieres porque no estás combinando los métodos adecuados para ello:

- obtener los datos usando un array asociativo
- no usar `array_push`, sino simplemente llenando tu array con cada fila
- construyendo un JSON sin forzarlo a objeto

Escribe el código así y obtendrás el objeto como dices que lo quieres:

```
<?php 
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas_maps") or die ("Problemas con la conexion");
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM registros2";
    $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas con la consulta");
    $c = array();
    while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $c[]=$reg;

    }
    echo json_encode($c)
?>
```

Deberías tener una salida así:

```
[{
    "id": "100",
    "cliente": "Carlos Luna",
    "metodo_pago": "Credito 30D",
    "hora_entrega": "14:15:00",
    "fecha_entrega": "2018-05-09",
    "sem_entrega": "19"
}, {
    "id": "104",
    "cliente": "sadfsadf",
    "metodo_pago": "Contado",
    "hora_entrega": "12:32:00",
    "fecha_entrega": "2018-06-18",
    "sem_entrega": "25"
}]
```

Comment: No me devuelve nada, amigo

Comment: @CarlosRobertoLunaOchoa me faltó esto `, MYSQLI_ASSOC` en el `while`, lo he editado, pon esa línea como está ahora y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Sigue sin devolver nada amigo, y no habra alguna forma de parsearlo en JS a como yo lo necesito?

Comment: @CarlosRobertoLunaOchoa ¿podrías poner en un comentario cómo tienes el código? Yo lo he probado con otros datos y me funciona. Debe ser que algo has escrito mal.

Comment: Aqui te dejo un Fiddle con el codigo completo, amigo: http://jsfiddle.net/u5v346fz/

Comment: El problema es que, tratándose de código que está en tu servidor, no puedo probar los datos del fiddle. No me queda claro si la consulta funciona y devuelve los datos en el formato indicado. Como te decía, lo he probado y me funciona, pero no me dices siquiera si la parte PHP funciona. En cuanto a leer los datos, sería muy fácil, supongamos que recibes el JSON en `res`, solamente harías esto: `var data =JSON.parse(res);
$.each(data, function(key, value)
{
 $.each(value, function(k, v)
 {
   console.log("k: "+k + "v: "+ v);
 });
});` en el segundo `each` mostraría cada clave/valor.